# How can a C# Windows Console application tell if it is run interactively

Tags: c#, console-application, user-interaction

How can a Windows console application written in C# determine whether it is invoked in a non-interactive environment (e.g. from a service or as a scheduled task) or from an environment capable of user-interaction (e.g. Command Prompt or PowerShell)?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

[Environment.UserInteractive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userinteractive.aspx) Property

Comment: FYI: "Environment.UserInteractive" returns true for a service when the "Allow Service to interact with desktop" option is checked.

Comment: My solution was simply to pass in a command line parameter to know I was in service mode. I think that was the only sure way anyone else could think of as well when I looked around. ;) I'm sure there's a way, or a hack, I just never needed to spend time to find it. ;) Perhaps there's a way to know you're hooked in with the service host somehow (parent process? not sure). Perhaps you can use the other answer on this page (http://stackoverflow.com/a/8711036/1236397) for testing if the window is open.

Comment: FYI: How to install a windows service (using installutil) with command line switches (start up parameters) can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19488134/1236397) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862580/using-installutil-to-install-a-windows-service-with-startup-parameters?rq=1);

Comment: This does not work if FreeConsole() (in kernel32.dll) has been called. In our case, the scenario is a program that supports both command-line and interactive mode. It starts as a console program, but as when the user gives no commandline options, the console is closed using FreeConsole(). Afterwards, Environment.UserInteractive is still true. Then, it is better to test if GetConsoleWindow() returns a valid pointer. If not, there is no Console.

Answer (score 48):

**[EDIT: 4/2021 - new answer...]**

Due to a recent change in the Visual Studio debugger, my original answer stopped working correctly when debugging. To remedy this, I'm providing an entirely different approach. The text of the original answer is included at the bottom.

---

1. Just the code, please...

To determine if a .NET application is running in GUI mode:

```cs
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandleW(IntPtr _);

public static bool IsGui
{
    get
    {
        var p = GetModuleHandleW(default);
        return Marshal.ReadInt16(p, Marshal.ReadInt32(p, 0x3C) + 0x5C) == 2;
    }
}
```

This checks the `Subsystem` value in the [**PE header**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable). For a console application, the value will be `3` instead of `2`.

---

2. Discussion

As noted in a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890104/determine-whether-assembly-is-a-gui-application), the most reliable indicator of **GUI** *vs.* **console** is the "`Subsystem`" field in the [PE header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#windows-subsystem) of the executable image. The following C# `enum` lists the allowable (documented) values:

```cs
public enum Subsystem : ushort
{
    Unknown                 /**/ = 0x0000,
    Native                  /**/ = 0x0001,
    WindowsGui              /**/ = 0x0002,
    WindowsCui              /**/ = 0x0003,
    OS2Cui                  /**/ = 0x0005,
    PosixCui                /**/ = 0x0007,
    NativeWindows           /**/ = 0x0008,
    WindowsCEGui            /**/ = 0x0009,
    EfiApplication          /**/ = 0x000A,
    EfiBootServiceDriver    /**/ = 0x000B,
    EfiRuntimeDriver        /**/ = 0x000C,
    EfiRom                  /**/ = 0x000D,
    Xbox                    /**/ = 0x000E,
    WindowsBootApplication  /**/ = 0x0010,
};
```

As easy as that code (in that other answer) is, our case here can be vastly simplified. Since we are only specifically interested in our own running process (which is necessarily loaded), you don't have to open any file or read from the disk to obtain the **subsystem** value. Our executable image is guaranteed to be already mapped into memory. And it is simple to retrieve the base address for any loaded file image by calling the [`GetModuleHandleW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandlew) function:

```cs
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandleW(IntPtr lpModuleName);
```

Although we might provide a filename to this function, again things are easier and we don't have to. Passing `null`, or in this case, `default(IntPtr.Zero)` (which is the same as `IntPtr.Zero`), returns the base address of the virtual memory image for the current process. This eliminates the extra steps (alluded to earlier) of having to fetch the entry assembly and its `Location` property, etc. Without further ado, here is the new and simplified code:

```cs
static Subsystem GetSubsystem()
{
    var p = GetModuleHandleW(default);    // VM base address of mapped PE image
    p += Marshal.ReadInt32(p, 0x3C);      // RVA of COFF/PE within DOS header
    return (Subsystem)Marshal.ReadInt16(p + 0x5C); // PE offset to 'Subsystem' word
}

public static bool IsGui => GetSubsystem() == Subsystem.WindowsGui;

public static bool IsConsole => GetSubsystem() == Subsystem.WindowsCui;
```

[official end of the new answer]

---

3. Bonus Discussion

For the purposes of .NET, `Subsystem` is perhaps the most—*or only*—useful piece of information in the **PE Header**. But depending on your tolerance for minutiae, there could be other invaluable tidbits, and it's easy to use the technique just described to retrieve additional interesting data.

Obviously, by changing the final field offset (`0x5C`) used earlier, you can access other fields in the COFF or PE header. The next snippet illustrates this for `Subsystem` (as above) plus three additional fields with their respective offsets.

> *NOTE: To reduce clutter, the `enum` declarations used in the following can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/pZL3Y7vM)*

```cs
var p = GetModuleHandleW(default);  // PE image VM mapped base address
p += Marshal.ReadInt32(p, 0x3C);        // RVA of COFF/PE within DOS header

var subsys = (Subsystem)Marshal.ReadInt16(p + 0x005C);        // (same as before)
var machine = (ImageFileMachine)Marshal.ReadInt16(p + 0x0004);          // new
var imgType = (ImageFileCharacteristics)Marshal.ReadInt16(p + 0x0016);  // new
var dllFlags = (DllCharacteristics)Marshal.ReadInt16(p + 0x005E);       // new
//                    ... etc.
```

To improve things when accessing multiple fields in unmanaged memory, it's essential to define an overlaying `struct`. This allows for direct and natural managed access using C#. For the running example, I merged the adjacent COFF and PE headers together into the following C# `struct` definition, and only included the four fields we deemed interesting:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct COFF_PE
{
    [FieldOffset(0x04)] public ImageFileMachine MachineType;
    [FieldOffset(0x16)] public ImageFileCharacteristics Characteristics;
    [FieldOffset(0x5C)] public Subsystem Subsystem;
    [FieldOffset(0x5E)] public DllCharacteristics DllCharacteristics;
};
```

> *NOTE: A fuller version of this struct, without the omitted fields, can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/EU1QJJ7i)*

Any interop `struct` such as this has to be properly setup at runtime, and there are many options for doing so. Ideally, its generally better to impose the `struct` overlay "*in-situ*" directly on the unmanaged memory, so that no memory copying needs to occur. To avoid prolonging the discussion here even further however, I will instead show an easier method that does involve copying.

```cs
var p = GetModuleHandleW(default);
var _pe = Marshal.PtrToStructure<COFF_PE>(p + Marshal.ReadInt32(p, 0x3C));

Trace.WriteLine($@"
    MachineType:        {_pe.MachineType}
    Characteristics:    {_pe.Characteristics}
    Subsystem:          {_pe.Subsystem}
    DllCharacteristics: {_pe.DllCharacteristics}");
```

---

4. Output of the demo code

Here is the output when a **console** program is running...

```
MachineType:        Amd64
Characteristics:    ExecutableImage, LargeAddressAware
Subsystem:          WindowsCui (3)
DllCharacteristics: HighEntropyVA, DynamicBase, NxCompatible, NoSeh, TSAware
```

...compared to **GUI** (WPF) application:

```
MachineType:        Amd64
Characteristics:    ExecutableImage, LargeAddressAware
Subsystem:          WindowsGui (2)
DllCharacteristics: HighEntropyVA, DynamicBase, NxCompatible, NoSeh, TSAware
```

---

**[OLD: original answer from 2012...]**

To determine if a .NET application is running in GUI mode:

```cs
bool is_console_app = Console.OpenStandardInput(1) != Stream.Null;
```

Comment: It's too bad that it requires System.IO, but this is still the best method I've found so far

Comment: +1 because I had a case where this method worked, while the Environment.UserInteractive method did not.  The case was an NUnit unit test where I wanted to abort the test when I pressed the ESC key.  You can't call Console.KeyAvailable when running from the NUnit GUI, so I needed a test to know when to skip that code.  Glenn's answer correctly identified when I was running in the NUnit GUI vs. running in a console window, while the Environment.UserInteractive property was TRUE in both cases.

Comment: @Trafz Note that `System.IO` is a *namespace* and the portion referenced here (`Console`) is implemented in *mscorlib.dll*, so you likely have neither an extra assembly to reference, nor an excess binding at runtime.

Comment: This worked for me for several years. However, this no longer works with the latest version of Visual Studio (Version 16.9.3). It seems VS is creating their own standard input when you run the application from VS. 
It still does work if you independently launch the compiled .exe, but you just can't debug from VS

Comment: @00jt Funny you mentioned this just now--after seeing your comment today almost immediately the same problem popped up in my regression (also on VS 16.9.3). Something definitely changed; as you mentioned, this worked for a long time but apparently the debugger has now decided to hook up *stdin*, meaning that perhaps perhaps the party is over for this long-standing hack...

Comment: @GlennSlayden I did find another way to do this looking at info in the Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() and then using the path to that file and calling somethign similar to what was done here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30890104/determine-whether-assembly-is-a-gui-application

Comment: @00jt I assume you're referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30892349/147511), which is probably how it should have been done in the first place. It's a great answer so thanks for pointing it out. I managed to improve on that idea so that it doesn't have to open any disk file, and I overhauled my answer here to show how to do it.

Comment: yep, that's what I was referring to. Thanks for the update, i might use that instead of my version.

Answer (score 6):

I haven't tested it, but [Environment.UserInteractive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.userinteractive) looks promising.

Answer (score 6):

**If all you're trying to do is to determine whether the console will continue to exist after your program exits (so that you can, for example, prompt the user to hit `Enter` before the program exits)**, then all you have to do is to check if your process is the only one attached to the console. If it is, then the console will be destroyed when your process exits. If there are other processes attached to the console, then the console will continue to exist (because your program won't be the last one).

For example*:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CheckIfConsoleWillBeDestroyedAtTheEnd
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // ...

            if (ConsoleWillBeDestroyedAtTheEnd())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . .");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        private static bool ConsoleWillBeDestroyedAtTheEnd()
        {
            var processList = new uint[1];
            var processCount = GetConsoleProcessList(processList, 1);

            return processCount == 1;
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint GetConsoleProcessList(uint[] processList, uint processCount);
    }
}
```

(*) Adapted from code found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160125-00/?p=92922).

Comment: I'm pretty sure GetConsoleProcessList() from the windows API was not directly callable from C# when I first asked this question, so this is a very nice update.

Comment: @JeffLeonard `GetConsoleProcessList` was directly callable from C# via P/Invoke with any .NET version, as long as you were running Windows XP or a later version of Windows - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsoleprocesslist#requirements

Answer (score 3):

A possible improvement of Glenn Slayden's solution:

```
bool isConsoleApplication = Console.In != StreamReader.Null;
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!
Whether it is an improvement would depend on what you are looking for.
Console.In would be affected by Console.SetIn.  In my use case, I was looking to see if the assembly being executed is WinForms.  In that case, I think Glenn's solution (Console.OpenStandardInput) would be more appropriate.
But it is good to have options!

Answer (score 2):

To prompt for user input in an interactive console, but do nothing when run without a console or when input has been redirected:

```
if (Environment.UserInteractive && !Console.IsInputRedirected)
{
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: `Console.IsInputRedirected` seems to work with `docker build` also