# How to read the Output Type in code

Tags: c#, continuous-integration

A common nuisance we have is having to switch this code below depending on whether we are testing locally or committing code for the build server.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Main entry point to the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Don't forget to uncomment this if committing (!)
        //var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] {new myservice()};
        //ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);

        // and re-comment this
        RunAsConsoleApp();

    }
```

It would be really useful if there was a way to test in the code to tell the output type i.e, and avoid all the 'oh-no I committed and broke the build' time wasting.

```
        if (IsConsoleApp)
        {
            Using(var host= new ServiceHost(typeof(myservice))
            {
               host.Open();
               etc....
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] {new myservice()};
            ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
        }
```

Comment: I assume `#if DEBUG` doesn't suffice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using the [Environment.UserInteractive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userinteractive.aspx) property in place of `IsConsoleApp`?

Answer (score 2):

`Environment.UserInteractive` does not detect if we have a console running, it only detects if the user can have some kind of interaction possibility to the running process. 
If you want to check if the application is a console application I found this working:

`bool is_console_app = Console.OpenStandardInput(1) != Stream.Null;`

All credits to Glen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188658/how-can-a-c-sharp-windows-console-application-tell-if-it-is-run-interactively).

Answer (score 1):

If you're all definitely not going to commit Debug builds.. then as long as there is a DEBUG constant defined under Project Properties > Build tab, you can try:

```
#if DEBUG
    RunAsConsoleApp();
#else
    RunNormally();
#endif
```

But then, this is still just as error prone if someone accidentally commits a Debug build.

Comment: as a side note this approach allows you to define your own statements


http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk(v=vs.80).aspx.


Could also recommend looking into the configuration manager to see if you couldn't use your own configuration, like Debug Local and Debug Remote incase that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a separate build configuration (e.g. Release - Service)  and have a conditional compilation statement to switch between code blocks.

See here for more:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691095(v=vs.71).aspx

So, in your Release - Service configuration, define a constant e.g. RELEASESERVICE.  Then use this like:

```
#if RELEASESERVICE

    etc
```