# Install Windows Service With Startup Parameter

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, windows-services

i am trying  to install windows service with start up parameters with batch file.

i have service name which is passed in installer to get instance name. also i want to set service start up parameter. with passing arg to installer i do not have problem. i am getting error on startup parameter setting.

code snippet:

```
  set serviceName=FSER

    C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe  /servicename="%serviceName%"  "%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\SERVER\%serviceName%\tser.exe "%serviceName%" " /logfile=install.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i Solved problem by adding parameter in Service installer "Assemblypath":

```
   protected override void OnBeforeInstall(IDictionary savedState)
        {                
                string parameter = "YOUR COMMAND LINE PARAMETER VALUE GOES HERE";
                var assemblyPath = Context.Parameters["assemblypath"];
                assemblyPath += @""" "" " + parameter + "";
                Context.Parameters["assemblypath"] = assemblyPath;
                base.OnBeforeInstall(savedState);
        }
```

Comment: This method leaves some ugly ". For me Context.Parameters["assemblypath"] = string.Format("\"{0}\" /i1 /d23", Context.Parameters["assemblypath"]); works as expected. The original assemblypath will be surrounded by " whereas the parameters stay unchanged

Answer (score 0):

Problematic use of quotes ? Try to escape inner quotes with backslashes, as

```
"\"myExeFile.exe\" \"myParameter\""
```

Don't really know about InstallUtil, but it that fails, and InstallUtil is needed, install service with InstallUtil but without parameters and then use sc.exe to reconfigure the service, including parameters in in binPath