# How do I detect if the application type is WinForms or Console?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a method inside a DLL library. How do I detect if it's called from a Winforms or Console application?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess a more important question is... why does it matter?  The behavior of the common code shouldn't change based on what calls it.

Comment: David is correct, common library shouldn't depend on the environment. But if you are really desperate, try if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188658/how-can-a-c-sharp-windows-console-application-tell-if-it-is-run-interactively) helps. Especially the second answer.