# How to know if application was run from console or explorer?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, console

I'm writing a small application that should run both as winform mode or console mode. The problem is that I don't know how my application was started-up. If it was started-up using console it should do some staff, other wise it should display a winform.

```
Friend NotInheritable Class Program
    Shared Sub Main()

        If The application was run in console mode then
            'Run console processes
        Else
            'Open winform
            Application.Run(New Form1)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Cheers in advance :) !

Comment: The above link is how you would normally implement it. Also check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188658/how-can-a-c-sharp-windows-console-application-tell-if-it-is-run-interactively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer for what you need, but it's in C#. You can simply use a C# to VB.net converter if you don't know C#, or convert it manually

Found from a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3346055/1388267

```
/// <summary>
/// A utility class to determine a process parent.
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ParentProcessUtilities
{
    // These members must match PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION
    internal IntPtr Reserved1;
    internal IntPtr PebBaseAddress;
    internal IntPtr Reserved2_0;
    internal IntPtr Reserved2_1;
    internal IntPtr UniqueProcessId;
    internal IntPtr InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;

    [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
    private static extern int NtQueryInformationProcess(IntPtr processHandle, int processInformationClass, ref ParentProcessUtilities processInformation, int processInformationLength, out int returnLength);

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the parent process of the current process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An instance of the Process class.</returns>
    public static Process GetParentProcess()
    {
        return GetParentProcess(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the parent process of specified process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The process id.</param>
    /// <returns>An instance of the Process class.</returns>
    public static Process GetParentProcess(int id)
    {
        Process process = Process.GetProcessById(id);
        return GetParentProcess(process.Handle);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the parent process of a specified process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="handle">The process handle.</param>
    /// <returns>An instance of the Process class.</returns>
    public static Process GetParentProcess(IntPtr handle)
    {
        ParentProcessUtilities pbi = new ParentProcessUtilities();
        int returnLength;
        int status = NtQueryInformationProcess(handle, 0, ref pbi, Marshal.SizeOf(pbi), out returnLength);
        if (status != 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(status);

        try
        {
            return Process.GetProcessById(pbi.InheritedFromUniqueProcessId.ToInt32());
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            // not found
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

You can get the handle of the parent process, then check its name to know whether it's explorer or command prompt

EDIT: Just got it converted to VB.net so you can use it directly:

```
''' <summary>
''' A utility class to determine a process parent.
''' </summary>
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure ParentProcessUtilities
    ' These members must match PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION
    Friend Reserved1 As IntPtr
    Friend PebBaseAddress As IntPtr
    Friend Reserved2_0 As IntPtr
    Friend Reserved2_1 As IntPtr
    Friend UniqueProcessId As IntPtr
    Friend InheritedFromUniqueProcessId As IntPtr

    <DllImport("ntdll.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function NtQueryInformationProcess(processHandle As IntPtr, processInformationClass As Integer, ByRef processInformation As ParentProcessUtilities, processInformationLength As Integer, ByRef returnLength As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the parent process of the current process.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>An instance of the Process class.</returns>
    Public Shared Function GetParentProcess() As Process
        Return GetParentProcess(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the parent process of specified process.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="id">The process id.</param>
    ''' <returns>An instance of the Process class.</returns>
    Public Shared Function GetParentProcess(id As Integer) As Process
        Dim process__1 As Process = Process.GetProcessById(id)
        Return GetParentProcess(process__1.Handle)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets the parent process of a specified process.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="handle">The process handle.</param>
    ''' <returns>An instance of the Process class.</returns>
    Public Shared Function GetParentProcess(handle As IntPtr) As Process
        Dim pbi As New ParentProcessUtilities()
        Dim returnLength As Integer
        Dim status As Integer = NtQueryInformationProcess(handle, 0, pbi, Marshal.SizeOf(pbi), returnLength)
        If status <> 0 Then
            Throw New Win32Exception(status)
        End If

        Try
            Return Process.GetProcessById(pbi.InheritedFromUniqueProcessId.ToInt32())
        Catch generatedExceptionName As ArgumentException
            ' not found
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
End Structure
```

Comment: I really hate people who downvote for no reason. Just tell me what your problem is in a comment after you downvote. God!