# Good approach to determine the PEFileKind of an assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reflection, portable-executable

In C# or VB.NET, I would like to know which would be the best approach to determine the [PEFileKinds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.pefilekinds?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) of an assembly loaded through **Reflection**. In other words, determine whether an assembly is a WinExe, Console application, or a Dynamic link library.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30892349/1248295) solution (the other proposed solutions in that question are not effective), but If I'm not wrong I think it implies to assume that the file loaded is a .NET assembly, and, seems a little bit tidy to manually parse the PE header.

I also found [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26817422/1248295) solution but reading the comments it seem not effective in some circumstances.

For those reasons, I wonder if exists a truly safe, managed way, preferably through **Reflection**, to determine the PE file kind of a loaded assembly.

I'm sure the `System.Reflection.Emit.PEFileKinds` enumeration does not exists only for decorative purposes, if that enum exists then its logic to think that there could be a member/function that I missed inside the **Reflection** namespaces  that internally use that enum to return the PE file kind of a `Assembly` object, however, I managed to look at the private members of the `Assembly` class through **Reflection** and other related classes and I found nothing relevant.

Comment: Given that `PEFileKinds` is in the `System.Reflection.Emit` namespace, it probably is only used when writing, not reading, in the regular .NET Framework reflection APIs. I can answer when I research it more myself, but in the meantime you might consider looking at `System.Reflection.Metadata` on NuGet (although it's not well-documented) or the third-party `Mono.Cecil` library.

Comment: If you don't want to analyze the PE format yourself, use an existing library like https://github.com/secana/PeNet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [a search of the reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/pefilekinds.cs,996c7e87dbf6fc4c,references), the `PEFileKinds` enum is only used in `AssemblyBuilder` and `ModuleBuilder` (and the non-public helper types for them). This enum and the classes are found in the [`System.Reflection.Emit` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit?view=netframework-4.7.2) - e.g., they're intended for writing assemblies, not reading.

However, [the official `System.Reflection.Metadata` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.Metadata/) exposes the relevant values of an assembly's PE header in its [`System.Reflection.PortableExecutable` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.portableexecutable?view=netcore-2.1). You can use these headers to reverse engineer the equivalent `PEFileKinds` value. Here's an example in C#:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filenameAndExtension))
{
    using (var peFile = new PEReader(stream))
    {
        var headers = peFile.PEHeaders;
        Console.WriteLine($"Reading {filenameAndExtension} with System.Reflection.Metadata");
        Console.WriteLine($"  IsDll: {headers.IsDll}");
        Console.WriteLine($"  IsExe: {headers.IsExe}");
        Console.WriteLine($"  IsConsoleApplication: {headers.IsConsoleApplication}");

        PEFileKinds reverseEngineeredKind;

        // NOTE: the header values cause IsConsoleApplication to return
        //       true for DLLs, so we need to check IsDll first
        if (headers.IsDll)
        {
            reverseEngineeredKind = PEFileKinds.Dll;
        }
        else if (headers.IsConsoleApplication)
        {
            reverseEngineeredKind = PEFileKinds.ConsoleApplication;
        }
        else
        {
            reverseEngineeredKind = PEFileKinds.WindowApplication;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"  Reverse-engineered kind: {reverseEngineeredKind}");
    }
}
```

I ran this code on assemblies I generated with `System.Reflection.Emit` to ensure its accuracy. The full program is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/Joe-K-Sewell/16bcb6ae63651acbc4ccc8ff122a94fc).

You can probably also get this information with third-party libraries, like [Mono.Cecil](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cecil/) or, as Lex Li mentioned, [PeNet](https://github.com/secana/PeNet).

Comment: Hi. First I want to comment that I will never understand what reason could have a person to downvote an answer like this. Secondly, my idea was to also avoid the usage of third-party libraries, however, since the library you mentioned is official from Microsoft then I'm more than satisfied with this solution. Also it works as expected. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also, it seem using this library I also could determine whether an assembly is strong-name signed, so I can avoid using unmanaged code implementing the native IClrStrongName interface to do the same. I know this is not part of my question but I'm very interested about it, maybe could you help me with a simple Yes/No answer here in the commentary box to let me know whether with this code I can determine strong-name signed or maybe I'm wrong about the meaning of this flag?: `bool isStrongNameSigned = peReader.PEHeaders.CorHeader.Flags.HasFlag(CorFlags.StrongNameSigned);`

Comment: @ElektroStudios I think that flag indicates whether the assembly claims to be strong-named, but it doesn't necessarily mean that the signature is valid.